# Is there any way to have an accessibility toolbar on a laravel project?

Tags: laravel, accessibility, toolbar

For my laravel project I need to implement an accessibility toolbar; however, I can't find an already developed toolbar. The only toolbar that I found was the [ADA toolbar](https://adatoolbar.com/) but it's for wordpress.

Do you know about any toolbar for laravel that I could use or should I create it myself?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: from a glance at the link it doesn't seem that it's wordpress specific - "wordpress" isn't mentioned anywhere on the page. Usually such "features" are automatically included on a webpage just by including some script you get from the vendor. But they don't actually help with accessibility - see [here](https://overlayfactsheet.com/) - so I would strongly advise to leave well alone and implement a properly accessible site from the ground up.

Comment: @RobinZigmond My site was built on an accessible way, but I'm looking for a toolbar that can help me with another aspects like changing the font size, the contrast, etc. I said it's for wordpress because I only found a download  [link](https://wordpress.org/plugins/accessibility-toolbar/). Sorry if i'm not clear, I'm pretty new on this topic.

Comment: I'm not an accessibility expert either, although it's something I'm getting more interested in and trying to educate myself - and others, where I can! - about. The biggest thing here, is that you just need your site to follow all the [WCAG guidelines](https://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG21/) (I say "just" but accept that this is often very tricky in practice, sadly), and then you don't need to bother giving specific options to users with assistive needs. Such users almost certainly already have tools to help them, in following WCAG you ensure your site will respect these rather than work against them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having a toolbar to allow various adjustments to a site such as font, color schemes, etc is an ok thing to do **as long as the toolbar isn't trying to replace making the site accessible**.  These latter tools are typically called "overlays" and many of them market themselves as saying you don't have to fix any accessibility issues and all you have to do is plugin their tool to your site (and pay them a fee every month).  It's blatent false advertising and several groups are working with the FCC regarding this.

- [A guide to accessibility overlays](https://siteimprove.com/en-us/accessibility/accessibility-overlays/)
- [Overlay Fact Sheet](https://overlayfactsheet.com/)
- [The Many Pitfalls of Accessibility Overlays](https://www.essentialaccessibility.com/blog/the-many-pitfalls-of-accessibility-overlays)
- [Accessibility Overlays May Not Make Your Site More Accessible](https://builtin.com/software-engineering-perspectives/overlay-accessibility)
- [Why Accessibility Overlay Solutions Fail to Protect or Serve](https://www.accessibility.works/blog/avoid-accessibility-overlay-tools-toolbar-plugins/)
- [Should I Use An Accessibility Overlay?](https://shouldiuseanaccessibilityoverlay.com/)

But with that out of the way, if you've already spent time making the site accessible, then having a toolbar to **help** with accessibility is ok.  A good example is the [State of California](https://www.ca.gov/).  Click on the "Settings" cog in the upper right...

[image]

and you'll see some handy adjustments you can make to the site.  Higher contrast, font size, and font face.

[image]

These are all helpful things.  The settings don't **replace** any accessibility work that's been done on the page.  The webiste already has good color contrast.  The website already has a good font (although there aren't any WCAG requirements when it comes to font.)

Making a website is not that difficult, contrary to what you may think.  Most (I'd say over 90%, probably higher) accessibility issues are super easy to fix.  It's usually the **volume** of issues that takes time.  Lots of easy fixes still add up to a lot of time if there are 1000s of them.

**Finding** accessibility issues might be the challenging part if you're not familiar with WCAG.  For anyone that's been doing accessibility testing for a few years, it's not that challenging.